# Migration of wordpress site from one server to another

Tags: php, wordpress

I have migrated WordPress site from one server to another. wp-Admin is working fine. But as on the main site there are languages installed so when I try to open `www.samarenterprises.org` it automatically by default redirect to `www.samarenterprises.org/en`

I face the error `page not found`

How ever one the old server its working fine `www.haramainlive.org`

Comment: Set `permalinks` again...

Comment: Thank buddy its fixed

Comment: Glad to help you... :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate entire website without losing contents, plugins, themes, post and pages by using duplicator plugin. It is automated process and you can watch the video tutorial [HOW TO CLONE WEBSITE TO NEW HOST USING WORDPRESS DUPLICATOR](http://wpviz.com/copy-website-backup-wordpress-duplicator/)